# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.faces.ui.DojoClientTextValidator

Tags: spring, jsf-2.2, spring-webflow, spring-faces

We are trying to upgrade our current JSF based application from Weblogic 11g to 12c. The application is currently built on
 
1) Spring Web Flow 2.3 
2) Spring Framework Core/MVC 3.2.1 
3) Primfaces 5.2 
4) Hibernate 4.0 
5) Spring faces 2.3

While upgrading to 12c, initially we got some error related to Spring jars and as per other posts suggestions to upgrade to higher version of Spring, we are now trying to upgrade the Spring framework jars to 
 
1) Spring Web Flow 2.4.6 
2) Spring Framework Core/MVC 4.3.11 
3) Primfaces 5.2 
4) Hibernate 4.0 
5) Spring faces 2.4.6

So with these jars we are getting the following exception related to DojoClientTextValidator which is no longer available in Spring faces 2.4.6 jar but have no idea why Spring is still try to load it.

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.faces.ui.DojoClientTextValidator
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1025)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:986)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:607)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:539)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Any ideas and help would be appreciated.
Thanks
-Raj

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle?  It would help to see the dependency tree as you are likely getting a bad version from somewhere.  `mvn dependency:tree` or `gradle dependencies --configuration runtime` or `gradle dependencies --configuration compile` depending on where this happens (gradle has lots of dependency trees).

Comment: It's also possible Weblogic is caching something or has some Spring libraries included by default that you may want to check.

Comment: We are not using maven/gradle, all the jars in lib and using ant to build the deployment files. I also think that weblogic have some jars which are conflicting with application libraries.